# Wubi error about "invalid tag data"

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, installation, wubi

I tried to install Ubuntu 10.10 and 10.04 through Wubi in Windows 7.

Even after I disable the firewall and antivirus I get this error again and again.

```
Invalid Tag data . check len(D=1,(ord(d) & 128)==128. recvd -> (<>
```

It becomes unable to install. I tried to install to c drive and e drive also.

Comment: I have the same problem ( exactly), Im trying to intall on both dell windows 7 machine along with a netbook. I receive the exact same error message! I think Im gonna post a thread on reddit in a alittle. So frustrating and their many boards about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's Mint Linux oriented, maybe this help: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/576166

If you read the tread it's about a workaround to disable internet connection during install or using --skipmd5check switch.

However I am not sure it's the really same issue, but they seems to be similar.

Answer (score -1):

You have to disconnect the internet conection while installing (unplug your LAN cable or switch your wireless lan off).